# Change direction of axis title and label in 3dplots in R?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have a question that might be easy for a person who is expert in R plot. I need to draw 3D plot in R. My data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c(489.4,  505.8,  525.8,  550.2,  576.6),
a2 = c(197.8,  301,    389.8,  502,    571.2),
b1 = c(546.8,  552.6,  558.4,  566.4,  575),
b2 = c(287.2,  305.8,  305.2,  334.4,  348.6), c1 = c(599.6,  611.4,  
623.6,  658,    657.4), c2 = c(318.8,  423.2,  510.8,  662.4,  656),
d1 = c(616,    606.8,  600.2,  595.6,  595),
  d2 = c(242.4,  292.8,  329.2,  378,    397.2),
e1 = c(582.4,  580,    579,    579,    579),
e2 = c(214,    255.4,  281.8,  303.8,  353.8))

colnames(df) <- rep(c("V1", "V2"), 5)
df.new <- rbind(df[, c(1, 2)],df[, c(3, 4)],df[, c(5, 6)],               
df[, c(7, 8)],df[, c(9, 10)])
df.new$Group <- factor(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), each = 5))
df.new$Class <- rep(c(1:5), 5)
```

I am drawing a 3D Plot using scatterplot3d package.

```
x=df.new$Class
y=V1
z=V2
scatterplot3d(x,y,z, pch = 16, color=colors,main="3D V1 v.s V2",xlab = 
"Class",ylab = "V1", zlab = "V2")
```

Now I want to do 2 modifications. One is to make the vertical title of those axis horizontal and the next is to put a label for values of x and for example put a label "first interval" for 1 in x values and so one and so forth. How an I do it?

Also, how can I make the points linear or plane instead of dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One is to make the vertical title of those axis horizontal

To do this you need to hide the current label, and use the text() function to add a rotated label in the correct spot; as described here [Rotate y-axis label in scatterplot3d (adjust to angle of axis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117769/rotate-y-axis-label-in-scatterplot3d-adjust-to-angle-of-axis#42118044)

```
set.seed(42)
scatterplot3d(rnorm(20), rnorm(20), rnorm(20), ylab = "")
text(x = 5, y = -2.5, "Y-axis", srt = 45)
```

> and for example put a label "first interval" for 1 in x values and so one and so forth. How an I do it?

From the documentation - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/scatterplot3d.pdf
Use the x.ticklabs attribute, for example:

```
xlabs <- c("first interval", "second", "third", "fourth", "this is 5")
scatterplot3d(x,y,z, pch =16,main="3D V1 v.s V2",xlab = "Class",ylab = "V1", zlab = "V2", x.ticklabs=xlabs)
```

> Also, how can I make the points linear or plane instead of dots.

Scatterplot3d offers "lines" and "vertical lines", for example:

```
scatterplot3d(x,y,z , type="l", lwd=5, pch=" ")
#or
scatterplot3d(x,y,z , type="h", lwd=5, pch=" ")
```

Comment: Your answers seems perfect except when I try to plot linear plot it just plots with one color and ignores other colors?

Comment: Also is it possible to plot a plane for each color?